How to force change a type parameter from a possible nullable type to a guaranteed non-null type
Consider a method like this
public static T WhenNotNull<T, TObject>(this T settings, TObject obj, Func<T, TObject, T> configurator)
{
    return obj != null ? configurator.Invoke(settings, obj) : settings;
}

It's going to be used in a NUKE build project like that
dotnet => dotnet.WhenNotNull(this as IHaveGitVersion, (d, o) => d.SetFileVersion(o.Versioning.AssemblySemFileVer))

It all works great, beside one thing
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>

This will make the analyzer complain about CS8602 Dereference of a possibly null reference for the variable o
SetFileVersion(o.Versioning.AssemblySemFileVer))

I know that I can just suppress it with !. But I would have to do this inside each WhenNotNull() usage.
Or I disable the nullable stuff altogether in the build project.
Is there a way to somehow tell the analyzer that TObject inside the Func<T, TObject, T> won't be null so I don't have to suppress it?
One possible solution I have is using the ? on obj parameter
public static T WhenNotNull<T, TObject>(this T settings, TObject? obj, Func<T, TObject, T> configurator)
{
    return obj != null ? configurator.Invoke(settings, obj) : settings;
}

But I am not sure if there are better solutions for this.

If TObject obj is ever going to be null (which it looks like it may be since you are null checking), the ? is required to remove the warning, and is the correct approach. This is a standard use case of the nullability question mark.

"One possible solution I have is using the ? on obj parameter" -  that is the solution, otherwise compiler will determine TObject as nullable, hence the warning.
